# D7 - Ckeditor buttons get messed up when moving a site from one server to other

Tags: 7, wysiwyg

I just moved a D7 site from one server to another and the Ckeditor buttons get messed up. Look my capture. How can I fix this?

I use the Adminimal Theme but it is not the problem. If I switch to Bartik the problem persist.

I already cleared caches and run Cron several times.

[image]

Comment: For good measure clear your browser cache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked Css settings on Ckeditor profile page?
[image]

Comment: Yes I have. But I just re-saved this page I the problem is gone. I guess it needed to be refreshed.  Thanks.

Comment: Happy to help, don't hesitate to voteup if it really helped you :)